# How does one consciously know if a reason is valid for believing in something?

Tags: epistemology

Say that you believe Adam murdered someone because his fingerprints were on the victim's neck with bruises and a very clear incentive and plot to murder the victim was discovered on his laptop. You consider these valid reasons to believe.

How does one know if these reasons are valid consciously? As in, what is the experiential feeling that marks these reasons being valid? If there is no feeling that a valid reason relies on, then how can one know?

Note that I am not just asking how one knows something in general, especially if "know" is defined to be pertaining to certainty. In my eyes, you can't be certain of anything except experience.

A better way to illustrate this is the argument from emotion fallacy. For example, just because you fear X, doesn't mean X is true. However, many human beings denote a feeling of "something clicking" or something "feeling just right" when something makes sense to them. But that is also just a feeling. And just because you feel X, doesn't mean X is true.

So if fear doesn't make your reasons for believing X invalid, and that "clicking" feeling doesn't make your reason for believing X valid, and since the validity of a reason doesn't seem to depend on any sort of conscious experiential signature, how do you experientially know if the reason you're currently thinking of is valid or not?

Comment: See [Belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/).

Comment: "experiential feeling"? Facts are known by experience: direct or indirect. Arguments are known by logic. Theories are known studying them. But no certainty at all.

Comment: In philosophy and logic, "valid" is a technical term, and it isn't what you mean here. To avoid confusion, you should change the word to "rational" or "strong" or something like that.

Comment: You are referring to only inductive reasoning. This is the reasoning that all sciences use. Unfortunately no science can offer certainty or 100 percent proof of anything. There is deductive reasoning which is different. Deductive reasoning can yield certainty. Inductive reasoning is easier to use & used more frequently.

Comment: @Logikal That makes it sound as if science is taking the easy way, the point is science has no choice but to take the route of induction as deduction requires certain axioms of which you know the truth value, which isn't the case for in natural sciences where things are never "certain" but only "reasonable to a degree of error". Though it also implores deduction by checking whether assumptions about the world would hold logically in the realm of math. Though in the end what matters is whether these assumptions describe the real world and not whether they would be neat if they were true.

Comment: You seem to be compaing an evidentiary basis for belief in your first example with an intuitive basis in your later examples.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out "validity" is actually a technical term in the realm of deductive reasoning. And it essentially just means that you can draw a conclusion from it's premises. So for example

> ```
> All trees are dead.
> The Great Oak is a tree.
> The Great Oak is dead.
> ```

would be a valid statement as "If A and B are true, it follows that C MUST be true as well". So a so called "fallacy" is usually a "non sequitur" which is Latin for "does not follow", meaning there's an error in the form so that C does not follow from A and B.

Now obviously A is false so the statement is valid, BUT not useful to determine the truth value of the conclusion as the case of "not all trees being dead" is not covered in any of the premises. If the statement would be valid and the premises were to be true that would be called a "sound" argument, btw.

Now the neat thing about deduction is that they actually express a certainty. Like if they hold they hold for every example and if there is one counter example they are false entirely. The problem with that is that we rarely deal with things that are this certain and so they are usually only suitable for assumptions and abstract logic.

For dealing with the real world we usually implore induction. In simple terms deduction determines the specific case from a general rule, whereas induction tries to derive a general rule from a specific case.

> if all balls are blue, the ball in my pocket is also blue (deduction)

> if I have only ever seen green balls, all balls might be green. (induction)

So the first expresses a certainty the second an assumption. The first could be "valid" or "invalid", the latter could be "weak" or "strong" (but not certain). So technically the entire inductive reasoning would be invalid because it doesn't follow, reliably all the time, from the premises. That being said a good guess is still often better than to have no idea at all so despite being invalid it could still be pretty useful, you just need to keep in mind that at the end of the day you're dealing with assumptions not certainties.

So in your case you're essentially looking at probabilities for these things to either be pure chance or you'd narrow down then group of people for whom these things could apply at the same time.

Like in order to commit the murder you had to be in the area at the specific time, which rules out the majority of the world, leaving you with people who live there +-  travelers. Maybe you can guess their sex, height, shape and so on. Which again all give reduce the number and add an error rate for these figures. Fingerprints also apparently have a [false positive rate of 1/1000](https://phys.org/news/2011-04-false-positives-rare-fingerprint.html). Which again significantly reduces the number of suspects adding a little more error. So the more questions you ask which are INDEPENDENT of the other questions the more people you would rule out for whom that would appear as well. So in the end that should narrow it down significantly and there are formulas that let you weight the results with their respective uncertainties giving you ideally a few testable subject or even just one and an estimated error rate for that.

And from there it's essentially politics to make a decision what you value more a low false positive rate (people being convicted despite being innocent) or a false negative rate (people roaming free despite being perpetrators). So whatever is decided, you'd chose a limit as to what is considered "beyond reasonable doubt" and if the estimated error is below that, this would be a strong claim.

Though of course if the murder victim had many enemies you might have many people with a strong motive and a plot to kill him on their laptops and maybe the bruises come from an earlier exchange and weren't the fatal incidence or someone used fingerprint gloves (do those exist?) or whatnot. So in the end it's still an assumption and even if the facts are clear you can still spin the narrative around those facts. Like what if the suspected murderer is a twin and both hated the victim but only one did it?

Though as said at least you'd have a strong claim as opposed to just picking up a random person from the street and argue "you did it, confess!".

Comment: Well said, but the OP asked about a feeling that they are correct and you explained logic. Like, Mr Spock probably couldn't say how to know you are in love.